# No imprime contenido de fichero. C

Tags: c, printf

Estoy intentando imprimir por pantalla el contenido de un txt ("hello world"), sin embargo lo único que imprime por consola es un símbolo raro (un cuadrado) . Estoy ejecutando el programa en la consola (Sistema operativo Debian Stretch) mediante el siguiente comando

```
gcc llamadas.c -o llamadas
./llamadas
```

y con la terminal abierta en la carpeta donde se encuentra el documento, por lo que no creo que sea problema de path.

Este es mi código, ¿qué es lo que me falta? ¿Puede ser por alguna librería?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int fd;
  fd=open("probando.txt",O_RDWR || O_APPEND);
  char cadena[50];
  read(fd,cadena,50);
  printf("%s\n", &cadena);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo con la documentación de open quizás quieras escribir:

```
fd=open("probando.txt",O_RDWR | O_APPEND);
```

Por otro lado, puesto que el nombre de un array es en realidad un puntero, yo escribiría:

```
printf("%s\n", cadena);
```

Comment: El nombre de un array no es un puntero, porque no ocupa memoria. Simplemente es un alias de la dirección base del array. Mirar este enlace donde lo comprueban con más detalles: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c#id5

Comment: Quizás la respuesta pueda dar a entender que el nombre del array es equivalente a una variable de tipo puntero, aunque no era lo quería decir, asi que gracias por la aclaracion.